# What is directory's blockmap? And how many disk I/Os will happen?

Tags: filesystems, inode

I am reading this [paper](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/osdi10/tech/full_papers/Beaver.pdf) from Facebook (Beaver). The paper says that

> We initially stored thousands of files in each directory of an NFS
>   volume which led to an excessive number of disk operations to read
>   even a single image. Because of how the NAS appliances manage
>   directory metadata, placing thousands of files in a directory was
>   extremely inefficient as the **directory’s blockmap** was too large to be
>   cached effectively by the appliance. Consequently it was common to
>   incur more than 10 disk operations to retrieve a single image. After
>   reducing directory sizes to hundreds of images per directory, the
>   resulting system would still generally incur **3 disk operations to
>   fetch an image: one to read the directory metadata into memory, a
>   second to load the inode into memory, and a third to read the file
>   contents.**

I have following questions:

1. What is the meaning of "directory's blockmap"? Does it refer to file containing the mapping between filenames and inode numbers?
2. In the end, paper says 3 I/Os are needed to read a file. In my opinion, there should be 4 I/Os. First I/O to load the directory inode (inode contains metadata). Second I/O to read the directory entries (that will give us file inode number). Third I/O to load file inode into memory. Fourth I/O to the read the file contents. Where am I wrong here?

Similar question has been asked before [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/354700/linux-how-many-disk-i-o-does-it-take-to-read-a-file-how-to-minimize-it) and [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/354017/linux-how-many-disk-i-o-does-it-take-to-read-a-file-how-to-minimize-it), but I could not find appropriate answer.